# laravel printing a recursive tree

Tags: php, laravel, tree

file.blade.php

```
@foreach($places as $p)
    <li>
     <a href="">{{ $p->name }}</a>
    @if($p->children->count())
          @include ('tree', ['entries' => $p->children]);
    @endif
    <li>
@endforeach

</ul>
```

I'am trying to print the tree recursively in my view, I have only 2 rows in the database(parent and child), here the problem is that the `p->children->count()` is returning an empty string, instead of 0 and is it threated as true, what is the correct way to count the children?

```
Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
```

because is returning true even if there no children

this is how I get it in the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = [];
    $data['places'] = Place::with(['children', 'parent'])->get();
    return view('places/index', $data);
}
```

UPDATED:

```
class Place extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Place', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Place', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your relationship for children?

Comment: how about @if(!empty($p->children) && $p->children->count()>0)

Comment: @RossWilson updated question

Comment: @koalaok tryed same error

Comment: did you try to dump and die the content of $p->children->count() ? it should be empty and test !empt should work... if not there's something wrong in your data structure.

Comment: can you show content of dd($p) ?